# angularjs uib-timepicker add variable runtime

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using uib-timpicker  for dates as input from user the problem is i want to add key to my data on runtime if something changes on the div e.g i want to add variable etiming.clockOut.edited to my data here is the code:

```
<div style="float:left" uib-timepicker key-handler=""  data-ng-model="etiming.clockOut.time" ></div>
```

Comment: etiming.clockOut is your object?

Comment: yes and want to add  
etiming.clockOut.edited = true on timepicker/div change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add dynamic key on change then simply use:

**ng-change="etiming.clockOut.edited=true"**

```
<divuib-timepicker key-handler=""  ng-change="etiming.clockOut.edited=true"  data-ng-model="etiming.clockOut.time" ></div>
```

or

create a function and on ng-change call the created function and assign anything you want in the function in your case :

```
  <div uib-timepicker key-handler=""  ng-change="callFunction(etiming.clockOut)"  data-ng-model="etiming.clockOut.time" ></div>
```

and in js file

```
$scope.callFunction = function(data) {
     data.edited =true //or false as you wish
}
```

Comment: will add runtime property on change?